# C# Using XSD schema as meta data for forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xsd

I want to create a bunch of data entry screens in an ASP.NET application based on a bunch of XSD schemas.

Are there any tools that can be used to do any of the following
1) Read in an XSD schema and generate C# busines objects 
2) Read in an xsd schema and generate form controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, at least for #1.  Check out xsd.exe.  It is included in the framework.

See this page on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

For #2 you could check out XForms (http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/Forms/, http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XForms/Load_from_XML_Schema)